# OnKeyboardActionListener android keys

Tags: android, keyboard, keypress, actionlistener, keylistener

I'm trying to implement a way to know when there is a press and a release of a key on a soft keyboard.  I have used the onKeyListener to get the down and the up of the key, but the problem with that is that it only works on a hard keyboard.  I have found the OnKeyBoardActionListener which seems to have this functionality.  The problem I am running into with this is that i need to get the KeyboardView from an edittext i am using for simple testing.

```
public class testing extends Activity implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener{
     EditText testingBox;
     TextView textbox;
     KeyboardView keyView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    textbox = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);


    testingBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);

    //keyView is null i need to get it somehow.  

    keyView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
}
//methods for the OnKeyBoardActionListener
}
```

if anyone could provide any advice on how i can get this keyBoardView or another way i can capture these soft keyboard presses and releases would be great.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only way to capture the exact press and releases of a softkeyboard is from within the IME. You can see the text changing via a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html).

I think this is partially because an IME may not have key down and up mechanisms.  An IME does not necessarily need to look like a standard qwerty keyboard.  It might be something like Swype, where you draw a pattern and words come out.